# Test class for trigger on Case and case comment objects

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, case, emailmessage

I'm getting 60% code coverage for my trigger,

Trigger is on case object where trigger will copy Cc, Bcc data from email message to custom field on case. Following is trigger and test class, suggest why it's not giving 100% or >75% code coverage.

Trigger:

```
trigger EmailCopy on Case (before update, before insert) {

        if (Trigger.isBefore)
        {
            //class to copy data from to, cc and bcc fields to custom field
            copyEmail.emailCopier(Trigger.new);

            //If any email is unread, will change email status indicator as new email
            copyEmail.emailupdater(Trigger.new);
        }
}
```

Class:

```
 public with sharing class copyEmail {



      public static void emailCopier (list<Case> caseList){

            for(Case each : caseList)
            {
                list<EmailMessage> add1 = [select ToAddress from EmailMessage where ParentId =:each.id AND ToAddress != NULL];
                list<EmailMessage> add2 = [select CcAddress from EmailMessage where ParentId =:each.id AND CcAddress != NULL];
                list<EmailMessage> add3 = [select BccAddress from EmailMessage where ParentId =:each.id AND BccAddress != NULL];

                //clear field to avoid email duplication
                if(each.Email_Data__c != null)
                {
                    each.Email_Data__c = null; 
                }

                //add email addresses in custom field
                for(EmailMessage x : add1)
                {
                    each.Email_Data__c = each.Email_Data__c + ' ' + x.ToAddress + ' ';
                }
                for(EmailMessage y : add2)
                {
                    each.Email_Data__c = each.Email_Data__c + ' ' + y.CcAddress + ' ';
                }
                for(EmailMessage z : add3)
                {
                    each.Email_Data__c = each.Email_Data__c + '  ' + z.BccAddress + ' ';    
                }
            }
        }

        public static void emailupdater (list<Case> cases){

            for(Case each : cases)
            {
                list<EmailMessage> status = [select Status from EmailMessage where ParentId =: each.id];

                for(EmailMessage x : status)
                {   
                    if(x.Status.contains('New'))
                    {
                        each.Indicator__c = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class copyEmailTest {
    static testMethod void testCaseFromEmail() {

        Test.starttest();

        Group testGroup = new Group(Name='test group', Type='Queue');
        insert testGroup;

        System.runAs(new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId()))
        {
            QueuesObject testQueue = new QueueSObject(QueueID = testGroup.id, SObjectType = 'Case');
            insert testQueue;
        }

        Case aCase = new Case(OwnerId = testGroup.Id);
        insert aCase;

        list <CaseComment> Comment = new list <CaseComment>();
        for(Integer i=0; i<Comment.size(); i++)
        {
            String parentID = Comment[i].ParentID; 
            Contact newcontact = [Select Email from Contact Where ID = :aCase.ContactID];

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            message.setSubject('A new External Case Comment has been posted');
            message.setPlainTextBody(Comment[i].CommentBody);
            message.setToAddresses(new String[] { newcontact.Email });
            message.setCcAddresses(new String[] { newcontact.Email });
            message.setBccAddresses(new String[] { newcontact.Email });

            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] {message});
        }

        aCase.Indicator__c = false;
        update aCase;

        aCase.Indicator__c = true;
        update aCase;

        Test.stoptest();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the test class which you run to cover this trigger. Without which we cannot determine why its not covering the trigger.

Comment: does the test class even insert an OLI?

Comment: What is your question ? Please consider that we'll need more info, context, see what you've written and to know why you're not sure how to provide test coverage before we know what to answer you.  You can use the edit button to provide more information.

Comment: Please verify the information and help me to get more reputation by marking upvote for this question.
Updated test class provided in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below test class :
To insert opportunityLineItem, we have to insert opportunity, product etc. Take help from the below code. Let me know if you have any issues

```
@isTest
private class Test_demoTrigger {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        // TO DO: implement unit test

        Test.starttest();
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name='NewAcc';
        insert acc;



        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name='NewOpp';
        opp.AccountId=acc.Id;

        opp.StageName='Prospecting';
        opp.CloseDate=Date.today().addDays(10);

        insert opp;

        Product2 Prod =  new Product2();
         Prod.Name='NewProd';
         Prod.IsActive=True;
         insert Prod;

        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
        pbe.Product2Id=Prod.Id;
      pbe.IsActive=True;
      pbe.UnitPrice=70;
      pbe.Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
      pbe.UseStandardPrice=false;

      insert pbe;

       OpportunityLineItem opli = new OpportunityLineItem();


        opli.UnitPrice = 57;
        opli.Quantity = 12;
        opli.OpportunityId=opp.Id;

        opli.PricebookEntryId=pbe.id;
        insert opli;
         Test.stoptest();

         }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for response, apparently my test class wasn't working, so updated with this one and got 86% code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you just need to create one opportunity record to start with the code coverage. Please find the code below -

```
@IsTest
private with sharing class Risk_NegativeQuantity_Test {

    testMethod static void testremoteClass_testmethod1()
    {

    Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity(
          Name = 'Test Oppt',
          CloseDate = System.today() + 90,
          StageName = 'Prospecting);
        insert newOpp;

        Test.startTest();
        //calling controller methods here        
        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```